# The difference between get + pp and be + pp

Tags: meaning, difference, verbs, participles

I was talking about what happened to me a few years ago.   When I said, "I got surprised to find out ....., or "The plant got damaged because of the typhoon." my sentences were corrected by a native speaker of English like "I was surprised" or "The plant was damaged."  I was told that the first two sentences wouldn't sound natural.  I'd like to know why they don't sound natural.  Could you explain that, please? I wonder if it has someting to do with the time.

Comment: You're too fond of the verb ***to get***. Idiomatically this *can* be used in contexts where ***to be[come]*** is more likely/correct. But it tends to sound "colloquial, uneducated" anyway, so I suggest you ***get*** used to using ***was*** instead of ***got*** wherever it seems "credible". You'll sound more like a native speaker that way.

Comment: @FumbleFingers I didn't realize it. No textbooks explain what you explained here.  Thank you very much.

Comment: But it's still difficult to figure out when I can use "get" and when I cannot.

Comment: @ tennis girl: I don't know Japanese (I assume you're a native speaker), but I have a suspicion there's something about using ***to get*** instead of ***to be*** in examples like yours that matches some aspect of Japanese usage. But note that to *get surprised to find out...* is totally unidiomatic, whereas your *plant got damaged* example is quite common (both *common = widespread **and** common = [slightly] uncouth*).

Comment: @FumbleFingers  I think my understanding of using "get" was wrong. Using " get+ adjective", I thought I could tell a sudden change of state and apply to any adjective. I never thought about whether they are idiomatic or colloquial. I've started to get the idea. Thank you so much.

Comment: There are some cases where using *get* does sound natural. For example, something is said to "*get* bigger", or a child can "*get* taller". In these cases, using *become*, while correct, sounds too formal. There are several options: "you *got* taller" (normal, colloquial) / "you've *gotten* taller" (also normal, and perhaps more grammatical) / "you've *become* taller" (overly formal).

Comment: Note that OAD says "In North American English, got and gotten are not identical in use. Gotten usually implies the process of obtaining something (*he has gotten two tickets for the show*), while got implies the state of possession or ownership (*he hasn't got any money*)."

Comment: @jtbandes: Yes, but that distinction concerns **get + noun** constructions. OP is asking about **get + adjective**, specifically where a **past participle** is being used "adjectivally".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From [BBC Learning English](http://www.bbc.co.uk/worldservice/learningenglish/grammar/learnit/learnitv90.shtml)...

> **Get** is more informal and is frequently used in speech; **become** is more formal and is more often used in writing. When used with *adjectives*, **get** indicates *growth* or *development* and can therefore be used as the preferred alternative to **become** in an informal register.

There are many other constructions where "correct" (idiomatically "normal") use of ***get*** may be tricky for learners, but we're focussing here on ***get + adjective***. Taking OP's examples plus a few more...

> 1: ? *I **got** surprised to find my wife was having an affair* (non-idiomatic)
>    2: *The tree **got** damaged in the storm* (informal version of ***was*** damaged)
>    3: *My wife **got** angry when I asked her about the affair* (informal version of ***became*** angry)
>    4: ? *My wife **got** red when I asked her about the affair* (non-idiomatic version of ***turned*** red, **blushed**)
>    5: *That's when things **got** nasty* (informal version of ***turned*** nasty).
>    6: ? *At first she **got** defensive and said he had seduced her* (usually non-idiomatic - see below)
>    7: ? *Finally she **got** tearful and begged me to forgive her* (also usually non-idiomatic)
>    8: ? *After talking for many hours, I **got** satisfied that she still loved me* (always non-idiomatic)
>    9: *But my bedtime mug of cocoa **got** cold during the argument, so I was still annoyed with her*

I would say #6 and #7 are *usually* "non-idiomatic" because many native speakers wouldn't use ***get*** there unless they specifically intended to convey the sense that *she was in complete control of her emotions at the time* (and was trying different approaches to "win" the argument).

Even I can't decide whether #9 is "idiomatically acceptable" - it seems to be some kind of borderline case for me, but no doubt others will draw the line somewhere different. All I can say is few native speakers would accept #2 or #4 above, but exactly why some usages of ***get*** are okay and others not is obscure.

---

TL;DR: Many aspects of how ***to get*** is used are subtle and/or not universally recognised (see the US ["got" vs "gotten"](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/gotten) distinction, for example, which is indifferently honoured by those BrE speakers who've now adopted the latter term).

My advice to learners is not to be seduced by the idea that frequent use of ***got*** will make you sound more like a native speaker. Usually if you get it *right* no-one will even notice - but you're bound to get it wrong *sometimes*. And although native speakers will invariably notice the "errors", they probably won't point these out to you - precisely because they don't know how to explain what's wrong in simple terms.

In short, learn the appropriate use of less informal/slangy alternatives like ***was, became, turned, went***, and stick to these except where you often hear native speakers using ***got***. Don't simply gravitate towards ***got*** because it seems like you can just learn one verb for all contexts. Unfortunately, it's not that easy!

Comment: You perfectly explained what I wanted to know here. At the same time I realized that my understanding of how to use "get" was completely wrong. It was eye-opening to me.I bear in mind what you wrote here, which I've never thought about before, and want to improve my English.  Thank you so much for these great explanations. I'm very grateful.

Comment: As the OP said, your explanation is very elaborate and hugely helpful in that it covers a lot of aspects so thoroughly. But if I may ask you about one case, which is the same expression I wrote in a comment for @Carl Alexander's answer, *We got sent a thumb*? This is a line from the American drama, The Marvelous Mrs. Maisel.

Comment: @SmartHumanism: Even today, *We **were** sent a thumb* would be far more likely, and I'd say the ***got*** version would have been extremely unlikely back in the 50s (when the drama is set) for native speakers. I don't know the full context, so I can't say *how* "defensible" the verb choice is there. It's no big deal though - both are at least "acceptable" in a relaxed spoken context. If the speaker is supposed to be "uneducated", that makes ***get*** even more credible, but it might *also* convey a slightly stronger implication of *something was **done to us*** (it didn't just ***happen***).

Comment: @FumbleFingersReinstateMonica Thank you very much for the elaborate explanation!

Answer (score 3):

The first example sounds entirely unnatural to a native speaker.  The second is a little ambiguous:  "got" is more colloquial than "was"; "damaged because of the typhoon" is a comparatively elevated locution:  so "got" feels out of place there.  A native speaker might, however, use "got" to say the same thing in a simpler way, e.g. "The tree got blown down in the storm."  That sentence is simpler because all the words are monosyllables, and because their meanings are less abstract:  "tree" is a narrower, more concrete category than "plant"; "blown down" less abstract than "damaged".  So the more colloquial verb fits right in.

Which is not to say that "was" in place of "got" would be wrong in that sentence:  both would be equally idiomatic.  I don't want to give the impression that there's a simple rule here:  this is very much one of those areas where you will just have to develop a feel for idiomatic usage.

Comment: Thank you. Yes, I'll have to develp a feel for that.

Comment: I am not the OP but I appreciate your explanation. Thank you. But I'd like to ask about *We got sent a thumb*, which is a line from an American drama, The Marvelous Mrs. Maisel. Is this natural?