# Prepared vs. Prepare & Was drunk vs. Got drunk

Tags: grammar, meaning, adjectives, vocabulary, passive-voice

"I'm preparing for my next exam".

"I'm getting prepared for my next exam"

"He was drunk" vs. "He got drunk"

Does "Get" change the meaning of "Drunk" & "Prepare"? Also, is "Be prepared" or "Be prepare"?

Comment: Does this answer your question? ["Be offered" vs "get offered"](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/177074/be-offered-vs-get-offered) Also [Comparing differences of “be/get” and “will be/will get”](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/163179/comparing-differences-of-be-get-and-will-be-will-get) and [The difference between get + pp and be + pp](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/29169/the-difference-between-get-pp-and-be-pp), among others

Answer (score 1):

In your first example, the two usages have exactly equivalent meanings

In your second example, the “got drunk” refers to a past interval of time, to a process. The “was drunk” refers to a past instant of time, to a state. The difference is slight because before the past instant when he was in the state of drunkenness, there was a past interval during which he put himself in that state.

It is “prepared.”